# References for DBContext, DBSet<> in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying to use ADO.Net Codefirst feature of latest Entity Framework 4.0. As part of that I have installed [Entity Framework CTP 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e094902-aeff-4ee2-a12d-5881d4b0dd3e&displaylang=en)  from Microsft and using [Scott's tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) to create the model first. Inside the tutorial `DBContext` and `DBSet<>` is specified. Could some tell what is the reference to be used in order to access this class.

I have used the following references however nothing happens for `DBContext` and `DBSet<>`

- System.Data.Entity
- System.Data.Entity.Design

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [CTP5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35adb688-f8a7-4d28-86b1-b6235385389d) instead it is newer version with some changes in API. You have to add reference to EntityFramework.dll which is installed in CTP directory - default is: c:\Program Files\Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework Feature CTP5\Binaries\EntityFramework.dll for 32bit system. On 64bit system it will be placed in Program Files (x86).

Comment: Could you please tell will it support for 64 bit .Net version?

Comment: Not anymore. Now you would just use nuget Install-Module entityframework

Comment: @TeunD: Yes, you can post it as separate answer. This answer was pretty valid for the version OP asked ...

Comment: Instead of referencing entityframework.dll manually you can install the EntityFramework package from Nuget

Comment: Post is old...but now I think the link is broken.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the Library Package Manager if you have it (it installs automatically with MVC 3.0).

From within your project in Visual Studio 2010, go to

```
Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console
```

From within your project in Visual Studio 2013, go to

```
Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console
```

In the console, after the `PM>` prompt, type

```
install-package entityframework
```

This will install the package and add the EntityFramework reference to your project.

Comment: Install-Package : Unable to find package 'entityframework'At line:1 char:1 ...any idea why?

Comment: Looking at NuGet-Solution package manager, I can see I have EntityFramework installed (v6.0.2)...but DbContext still could not be found. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Use "DbContext" vs "DBContext", and "DbSet" vs "DBSet". The case sensitivity is the issue.

Comment: Thomas, I have just speciied the code, not copying and pasting this. I used the correct case in my code as it was copied from original tutorial. However thanks for letting me know that the keywords are in incorrect case. Cheers.

Comment: thats it...I did the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

To add EF to your project use the Package Manager Console and issue the command:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

You shouldn't link directly to the DLLs' installed location as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

The blogpost mentions the assembly:

> The DbContext and DbSet classes used
>   above are provided as part of the EF4
>   Code-First library.  You’ll need to
>   *add a reference to the*
>   ***System.Data.Entity.CTP*** assembly that
>   is installed into the \Program
>   Files\Microsoft ADO.NET Entity
>   Framework Feature CTP4\Binaries
>   directory to reference these classes. 
>   You’ll also want to add a “using
>   System.Data.Entity” namespace
>   statement at the top of your
>   “NerdDinners” class file.

However I do believe the new CTP5 includes some changes to codefirst, so I would suggest to take a look at that one instead.

Comment: Could you please tell will it support for 64 bit .Net version?

Comment: I am unsure if there are 64bit assemblies in the CTP. If not, your project will need to target x86.

Answer (score 1):

I was following the MvcMusicStore Tutorial (using Mvc 4 instead of Mvc 3).

I found in Part 4 I was having issues with this (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4).

When I added the following reference *using System.Data.Entity;*, I got the following error:

*the type or namespace name 'entity' does not exist in the namespace '`system.data`'*

@Fecklmore's solution worked for me.

Open the Package Manager Console by going to Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console.

Then type in the following:
*Install-Package EntityFramework*

This will install EntityFramework (i.e. EF) into your project, and will eliminate the error above.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .NET 3.5 then change your target framework to .NET 4.0

Comment: Thanks indeed @Arek Bee, I have used .Net 4.0 however some how reference is not there for Entity due to some reason. Later after installing the CTP5 everything was fine