# Dynamic Data IObjectContextAdapter missing reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-5

I have a fresh install of VS2012 with Update 2. I create a new project of "ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application". I then add an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" which I generate from an existing SQLServerExpress database.

However when I go to build the solution i get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'IObjectContextAdapter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

That appears to be declared in `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure` but I cannot find that assembly anywhere. I have verified that I have EF5 is installed for the solution as my packages.config shows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

The EntityFramework reference properties shows:

> RuntimeVersion: v4.0.30319
>     Version: 5.0.0.0

and in web.config I have:

```xml
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </assemblies>
```

This looks wrong as it should say 5.0.0.0? However changing it has no effect whatsoever. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, since you're wondering if anyone has any input - please take a look at [what if I don't get a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I have had a look and will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting this to compile turned out to be very easy. I needed to add:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
```

to Global.asax.cs. Seems that the T4 template does not include this be default.

Comment: would never or happened if you had resharper ;-) Missing a using statement, or searching for them is a pain.

Comment: Strangely enough R# did not complain or advise about importing the necessary assembly

Comment: Using VS2013 - also had to install `EntityFramework` NuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the EntityFramework Nuget package installed for your project.

Right-click on the Solution from the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, click Manage Nuget packages for solution and install EntityFramework.

Once it is installed, I still had the error, but then did a reinstall:

`Update-Package -reinstall`

Do this in the Package Manager Console (View > Other windows > Package Manager Console).
Now everything is good!

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257676/125938

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure" %>
```

adding this line to the top of the global.asax works as well.