# Global asax failing to compile "module system.data.entity version=4.0.0.0 should be referenced"

Tags: c#, asp.net

After converting a project from a website project to a web application project, the site fails to run complaining that global.asax cannot compile because:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

But I am referencing System.Data.Entity. If I remove the import line and reference it directly I get:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

But I am referencing System.Data.Entity.

I have tried removing it from references and re-adding it several times, as well as deleting my /bin/ folder and recompiling, etc.

I have also tried manually referencing the /v4.0/ System.Data.Entity dll instead of the default one from /v4.5/ but that also did not work.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972426/the-type-or-namespace-name-entity-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-data help?

Comment: No it did not, I had tried that too. I have an update - the web application is .net 4.5 and the project it is calling is .net 4.0. This I believe shouldn't be a problem but the system.data.entity dlls look different despite having the same version tag (v4.0.0.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the web.config fixed this issue:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
   <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
   </assemblies>
 </compilation>
```